# How does + operator work in Java?

Tags: java

I am providing some code below with its compiled class.

```
public class PlusOperator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a=10;
    int b=20;
    int c =a+b;

    String s1 = 1+3+"f";
    String s2 = "f"+1+2;
    String s3 = (1+3)+"f";
    String s4 = "f"+(1+3);

}
}
```

Compiled class with Java 1.6

```
  // Compiled from PlusOperator.java (version 1.6 : 50.0, super bit)
public class question.PlusOperator {

  // Method descriptor #6 ()V
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 1
  public PlusOperator();
    0  aload_0 [this]
    1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [8]
    4  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 3]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 5] local: this index: 0 type: question.PlusOperator

  // Method descriptor #15 ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  // Stack: 2, Locals: 8
  public static void main(java.lang.String[] args);
     0  bipush 10
     2  istore_1 [a]
     3  bipush 20
     5  istore_2 [b]
     6  iload_1 [a]
     7  iload_2 [b]
     8  iadd
     9  istore_3 [c]
    10  ldc <String "4f"> [16]
    12  astore 4 [s1]
    14  ldc <String "f12"> [18]
    16  astore 5 [s2]
    18  ldc <String "4f"> [16]
    20  astore 6 [s3]
    22  ldc <String "f4"> [20]
    24  astore 7 [s4]
    26  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 7]
        [pc: 3, line: 8]
        [pc: 6, line: 9]
        [pc: 10, line: 11]
        [pc: 14, line: 12]
        [pc: 18, line: 13]
        [pc: 22, line: 14]
        [pc: 26, line: 16]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 27] local: args index: 0 type: java.lang.String[]
        [pc: 3, pc: 27] local: a index: 1 type: int
        [pc: 6, pc: 27] local: b index: 2 type: int
        [pc: 10, pc: 27] local: c index: 3 type: int
        [pc: 14, pc: 27] local: s1 index: 4 type: java.lang.String
        [pc: 18, pc: 27] local: s2 index: 5 type: java.lang.String
        [pc: 22, pc: 27] local: s3 index: 6 type: java.lang.String
        [pc: 26, pc: 27] local: s4 index: 7 type: java.lang.String
}
```

My Questions:

1. How + operator works with String and int?
2. If you see the compiled code then String "+" is evaluated at the time of compilation with int also but in case of "+" only with int is performed at runtime. Why?

Comment: Try int c = 10+20; I think the diference is constants vs. variables, not string + vs int +.

Comment: All your `String` variables are initialized with constant expressions. Your `c` variable is not initialized with a constant expression.

Answer (score 5):

`a` and `b` are variables -- their values are only known at runtime<sup>1</sup>. However, `1`, `f` and `3` are constants so the compiler is smart enough to compute the result and include it in the bytecode. So expressions like `3` + `f`  are automatically compiled to the constant `3f`.

This has nothing to do with the operands being of type `int` or `String`. Try the same with `String`s:

```
String str = a + b;
```

and you'll see a call to `StringBuilder#append(String)` in the compiled code.

---

<sup>1</sup> An exception is when the variables are declared `final`, so in the following code:

```
final int a=10;
final int b=20;
int c = a + b;
```

`c` is directly assigned the value `30` in the bytecode:

```
bipush 10
istore_1
bipush 20
istore_2
bipush 30
istore_3
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Now got some clear picture about it.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting into the semantics of how the compiler works.  It is parsing your code and then if viable converting it to bytecode.  If the "+" operator is used in a string it acts one way if use in a binary expression then it acts another.  The operator is overloaded.

1. The "+" operator is overloaded.
2. This is code optimization done in the compiler.